# VBA getting textbox to display text and variable

Tags: vba

I'm using Word 2010 and trying to get a text box to display a variable and then some text following the variable.

I can code it vice versa like:

```
Private Sub OverallScore_Click()

OverallTotalScore = Attendance + DiligenceTotalScore + QualityTotalScore + SafetyTotalScore + TeamworkTotalScore + SkillsTotalScore

Select Case OverallTotalScore
    Case 0 To 69
        OverallScoreTextBox.Text = ("Rate increase $0.20 " & OverallTotalScore)
    Case 70 To 77
        OverallScoreTextBox.Text = ("Rate increase $0.25 " & OverallTotalScore)
    Case 78 To 84
        OverallScoreTextBox.Text = ("Rate increase $0.35 " & OverallTotalScore)
    Case 85 To 92
        OverallScoreTextBox.Text = ("Rate increase $0.45 " & OverallTotalScore)
    Case 93 To 100
        OverallScoreTextBox.Text = ("Rate increase $0.50 " & OverallTotalScore)
    End Select
```

However, I want it displayed as score first and then the text

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
Private Sub OverallScore_Click()

OverallTotalScore = Attendance + DiligenceTotalScore + QualityTotalScore + SafetyTotalScore + TeamworkTotalScore + SkillsTotalScore

Select Case OverallTotalScore
    Case 0 To 69
        OverallScoreTextBox.Text = (OverallTotalScore & " Rate increase $0.20")
    Case 70 To 77
        OverallScoreTextBox.Text = (OverallTotalScore & " Rate increase $0.25")
    Case 78 To 84
        OverallScoreTextBox.Text = (OverallTotalScore & " Rate increase $0.35")
    Case 85 To 92
        OverallScoreTextBox.Text = (OverallTotalScore & " Rate increase $0.45")
    Case 93 To 100
        OverallScoreTextBox.Text = (OverallTotalScore & " Rate increase $0.50")
    End Select 
End sub
```

The `&` is used to build your string (by concatenating them), so you can just switch what is on either side easily

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I was confusing the use of the & when it is used in C++